# How to grep ranges of numeric sequences from a column that contain several sequences

Tags: arrays, sorting, awk, sed, grep

I'm new writing bash scripts and have the following question; how can extract ranges (first and last value) from a column which contains several incremental and decremental numeric sequences that can increase or decrease by 3 and jump to the next sequence once it detects that the increment is >3 e.g.:

```
1
4
7
20
23
26
100
97
94
```

It is required to receive as an output:

```
1,7
20,26
100,94
```

Comment: not possible with `sed` (well, realistically, anyway). `awk` solutions below look usable. Also, S.O. is designed to help people with their programming problems, you're expected to show your best attempt to solve the problem. Before posting more questions here, please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, my mistake for not posting my first attemps, good to have the information suggeted. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==1||sqrt(($0-p)*($0-p))>3{print p; printf "%s", $0 ", "} {p=$0} END{print $0}' file

1, 7
20, 26
100, 94
```

Explained:

```
NR==1 || sqrt(($0-p)*($0-p))>3 {  # if the abs($0-previous) > 3
    print p                       # print previous to end a sequence and
    printf "%s", $0 ", "          # start a new sequence
} 
{ p=$0 } 
END { print $0 }
```

Comment: Thanks James for the solution presented and explained, it fits to my current needs. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

this awk script gives you expected output:

```
awk '{v=$NF}
    NR==1{printf "%s,",v;p=v;next}
    (p-v)*(p-v)==9{p=v;next}
    {printf "%s\n%s,",p,v;p=v}
    END{print v}' file
```